# Python text processing with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I use python 2.7.5.
I have got some files in the directory/sub directory. Sample of the `file1` is given below

```
Title file name
    path1 /path/to/file
    options path2=/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,/path/to/file3,/path/to/file4 some_vale1 some_vale2 some_value3=abcdefg some_value4=/path/to/value some_value5
```

I would like to insert the text `/root/directory` in the text file. Final outcome i would like to have is as followes:-

```
Title file name
    path1 /root/directory/path/tofile
    path2=/root/directory/path/to/file1,/root/directory/path/to/file2,/root/directory/path/to/file3,/root/directory/path/to/file4
    options some_vale1 some_vale2 some_value3=abcdefg some_value4=/path/to/value some_value5
```

The names `path, options and path2` are same in all files. The files in the directory/subdirectory required to be modified with the same outcome as above. I tried to use the `re.sub` to find and replace the string. However I never got the output i wanted.

Comment: Could you put the `re.sub` that you have tried?

Comment: `re.sub(r"([ \t =,])/", replace_text, text)` where `replace_text=/root/directory` and text is the content of the file loaded with `.read()`. As of now i am just trying to figure out replacing/inserting. Getting path2 line in to next line is a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got the answer from Bohemian and Jerry. Got it working with combined code.

```
str = re.sub(r'(options) (\S+)', r'\2\n    \1', re.sub(r'([ \t =,])/', replace_text, text))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner does the entire transformation:

```
str = re.sub(r'(options) (\S+)', r'\2\n    \1', str.replace('/path/', '/root/directory/path/')
```

See a [live demo](http://codepad.org/I5IpoYcW) of this code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
result = re.sub(r'([ \t =,])/', replace_text, text, 1)
```

The last `1` is to indicate the first match only, so that only the first path is substituted.

By the way, I think that you want to conserve the space/tab or comma right? Make replace_text like this:

```
replace_text = r'\1/root/directory/'
```

Comment: That worked perfectely. However i had to remove ad i needed to replace all matching string. Can you tell me what does "\1" does in the `r'\1/root/directory/'` Now comes the second part. How do i get the path2 line to the next line?

Comment: @sundar_ima Sorry, I didn't get notified of your comment :( The `\1` matches the captured group, so that you're keeping the part you captured; otherwise, it'd end up as `path1/root/directory/path/tofile`. Also, that's all right, I thought that `path2` was separate and would require a separate `re.sub`. Are the parts in the `options` separated by space? And is there always 4 paths and 5 values?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, `option` is always seperated by space and even `path2=/path/to/file1` also seperated by space. There are some cases where path1, options and path2 are already in different lines.